# Does Safari implement the most current protocol for web sockets?

Tags: html, websocket

Straight from the first line of the HTML5 Rocks tutorial on web sockets it is not working.

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo', ['soap', 'xmpp']);
connection.onopen = function () { alert("open"); };
connection.onerror = function () { alert("error"); };
```

It works in chrome, opera, ie. It doesn't work in Safari. Am I doing something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xSNpM/2/

Comment: i think i just got the answer. im on an old version of safari and there will be NO MORE NEW VERSIONS OF SAFARI ON WINDOWS!?!? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451835/does-safari-implement-the-most-current-protocol-for-web-sockets

Comment: Did you mean to link to this question in your comment?

Comment: http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/25/apple_kills_windows_pc_support_in_safari_60

Answer (score 0):

apple stopped updating safari on windows. this works on an up to date version of safari.